# Method undefined by the type

Tags: java, android, string, methods, package

I am trying to pass a string from "mainActivity" to a method "getDate(String s)" in class "GuassAlgorithm", found in the same package.

The method returns a string.

However, I get "The method getDate(String) is undefined for the type MainActivity" on both calls of the method. (String date = getDate("date") is superfluous, it is to verify that the error is repeatable)

I have placed comments above the linesof code in question.

Below is Main Activity:

```
package dayOfWeekApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.example.com.piercestudio.R;

import dayOfWeekApp.GuassAlgorithm;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//The method getDate(String) is undefined for the type MainActivity on this line

```
String date = getDate("date");

    final Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final EditText editTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
```

//The method getDate(String) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

```
            resultView.setText(getDate("10/25/1980"));
        }

    });        
}
```

Below is the GaussianAlgorithm class.

```
}

package dayOfWeekApp;

public class GuassAlgorithm {

public String getDate(String s){

    s = "10/25/1980";

    int day = Integer.parseInt(s);
    String weekDay = "error";

    //
    int centuries[][] = {{4, 1700}, {2,1800}, {0,1900}, {6,2000}, {4,2100}, {2,2200}, {0, 2300}, {6,2400}, {4, 2600}};
    Object months[][] = {{1, "January", 0, 6}, {2, "February", 3, 2},{3, "March", 3, 3}, {4, "April", 6, 6}, {5, "May", 1, 1}, {6, "June", 4, 4}, {7, "July", 6, 6}, {8, "August", 2, 2}, {9, "September", 5, 5}, {10, "October", 0, 0}, {11, "November", 3, 3}, {12, "December", 5, 5}};
    Object days[][] = {{0, "Sunday"}, {1, "Monday"}, {2, "Tuesday"},{3, "Wednesday"}, {4, "Thursday"}, {5, "Friday"}, {6, "Saturday"}};

    //t.charAt(0)[]
    int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6, 8)) * 1000;
    weekDay = Integer.toString(yearInt);

        return weekDay;
}
}
```

Do not make fun of me for my use of arrays. I'm used to Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to access it on the instance of an object:

```
GuassAlgorithm ga = new GuassAlgorithm();
ga.getDate("10/25/1980");
```

Or change the algorithm to static and access it that way:

```
public static String getDate(String s) { ... }

GuassAlgorithm.getDate("10/25/1980")
```

What is happening is it is looking for the getDate method in the current context but it doesn't exist.  So you have to provide the context.